# How to set a default environment for Anaconda / Jupyter?

Tags: ipython, virtualenv, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda for my Machine Learning course. I'm using it as IPython (Jupyter) notebook, in which we have lessons. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Basically, I always run it from Terminal with:

```
jupyter notebook
```

I have created new environment called `su_env` from `root` environment (exact copy) with one package added. Now, I'm wondering: how can I set environment `su_env` as default one? I have dozen of notebooks so it's annoying to set up each time for every notebook the environment, in "web" GUI of Jupyter.

**EDIT:** I'm interested in a solution where you don't have to set environment before running notebook. My logic is that, somehow, automagically, jupyter sets `root` environment on its own while starting up. Because of that, I'm wondering is it possible to set some config file or something so jupyter sets `su_env` instead of `root`. Also, if you know that's not possible (and why), I would like to know that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default Anaconda python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First activate the conda environment from the command line, then launch the notebook server.

For example:

```
$ source activate env_name
$ jupyter notebook
```

[image: jupyter notebook list of environments with env_name as the default environment]

Note: This might only work with environments that were created from within Jupyter Notebook, not environments that were created using `conda create` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that UI but I thought that I can set the default in that UI by putting checkmark under *Default?* or something like that. I'm wondering that there is no other option so you don't have to activate and deactivate environment for each session. So I will wait some more time to see if someone has the other answer.

Comment: What if I use `python3 -m venv env` and I don't see `conda` menu ?

Answer (score 4):

In your `~/.bashrc`, include the line:

```
alias jupyter="source activate su_env; jupyter"
```

This will condense the two commands into one, and you will activate `su env` whenever you call jupyter notebook or lab or whatever

Answer (score 1):

Edit your bashrc and add `source activate su_env` then that env will always be active. To switch back to to root (or any other env) `source activate env_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this on conda prompt:

> conda activate env_name

> jupyter notebook

source activate env_name gives me an error: 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.