# Tensorflow installation issue on Win 10

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and tried to install into Anaconda. I followed the instruction to the dot from tensorflow.org. I encountered no problem encountered but in python shell when i perform import tensorflow as tf, I got this error message, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'".

Please advise what to do to install tensorflow.

I already followed the previous post on conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6 but to no avail.

Comment: you should select the environment you installed tensorflow in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984238/how-to-set-a-default-environment-for-anaconda-jupyter