# Can I open Jupyter notebook in a non-conda environment?

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hi I just installed conda.

When I open my terminal and type 'jupyter notebook', it automatically open it with conda environment.

I want to know if it is possible to open it in a non-conda environment? (that's to say, conda is now set as default when I open it, right?)

Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccElw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Conda is default environment for you now. For change
First activate the conda environment from the command line, then launch the notebook server.

For example:

```
$ source activate env_name
$ jupyter notebook
```

You can find more information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38984238/how-to-set-a-default-environment-for-anaconda-jupyter)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely enabled auto activation of the conda environment during installation. Take a look at [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default) to disable it (most likely via `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`). Then, you can double check via `which python` that you're not getting the conda version and install jupyter with your non-conda, system Python environnment - via `python -m pip install jupyter`.