# Activate Anaconda Python environment *persistently* in Windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I can't figure out how to setup my Windows 7 machine so that it "always" finds my Python 3.6 Anaconda environment, which is not my root env.  I don't want to have to do "activate ..." in a cmd window every time I want to use that env.  And besides, there's a Spyder item in the start menu, for 3.6 (separate from default env), which won't work.  I assume because of an env issue.

A robust solution greatly appreciated.

Dave

Comment: Try the suggestion for windows in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40777297/5014455)

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm after.  I want the Python environment that "plain" Windows sees to be my Pyhon 3.6 env.  Why?  Because I run Spyder, which is a Windows app, from the start menu.  No cmd in the loop.

And whatever happened to autoexec.bat and config.sys?  Surely I'm not so old that no one else remembers this...

Comment: To run the Spyder item, which I assume is a shortcut to ``spyder`` in command line, it must be in the corresponding environment. To fix this issue, check if the Spyder item points to a .bat file or some shell file. If it is, then perhaps all you have to do is updating the file to activate the right environment before calling ``spyder``.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where every time I opened anaconda prompt it started with 'base' as the default environment. But the issue was that I was mostly working in a different custom environment so I had to activate it each time I wanted to use it.
Here is the solution I found for autoactivating my preferred environment on a Windows 10 system:

> - Open anaconda prompt & use 'conda env list' to find the location of the environment you wish to use.
>   [image]
> - Go to the start menu, right-click 'Anaconda Prompt' and go to file location.
>   [image]
> - Create a copy of its shortcut
> - Open its properties & change the target to the location of your preferred environment.
>
>   [image]

Now every time you open anaconda prompt through this shortcut it will automatically load your chosen environment.