# How to set system wide default Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, anaconda

I am running the latest Anaconda Python 3.6. I would like to switch to Python 2.7 **system wide**.

I searched [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment) and found a way to change the python environment in MacOS by creating a new python environment and then running `source activate python2`. Great, but that only works in the current terminal session.

```
(python2) $ ~/
```

I have Eclipse IDE running that needs Python 2.7 for certain things. I can just dereference Anaconda in the path by changing the `~/.bash_profile`, but that's not my question. I am looking for a way to change the default Ananconda python environment from 3.4 to 2.7 *system wide* and not just in one terminal session.

I found this in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment):

```
conda config --set core.default_env=python2
```

but I am getting an error:

```
conda config: error: argument --set: expected 2 arguments
```

Surely, there must be a way to switch Anaconda based environments system wide?

Comment: `conda config --set` collects the next two argument separated by a space, not an equal sign.  **I don't know if that command with work**.  But the correct syntax would be: `conda config --set core.default_env python2`.  As a follow-on question: are you trying to create a new environment, and set it as the default root environment for Anaconda?  Or are you trying to switch the current installation to Python 2.7?  (Switching the root to 2.7 is not possible, you would need to reinstall Anaconda).

Comment: @James Thanks for your response. I am trying to change the default Anaconda root environment.

Comment: I would recommend uninstalling and installing Anaconda2.