# How to change default conda environment in Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I have Anaconda installed in my machine with two environments one is `base`(default) and other is `vision`.

Whenever I open Anaconda Prompt, it opens in the base environment and I have to change the environment manually using

```
$ activate vision
```

So I'm looking for a way to open Anaconda Prompt in my `vision` environment by default.

Is it possible to do so?

- OS: Windows10
- Anaconda: 4.5.11

*P.S:  I have already gone through the similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment). Accepted answer doesn't provide a solution here as my both python versions are 3.6.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment

Comment: @VincentRodomista I have already linked that and mentioned accepted answer doesn't provide solution in my case.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Did you see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777297/2449192 It looks like it will answer your case...

Comment: Are you using `cmd.exe`, `Powershell` or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with the path and stuff in my `.bashrc` file, I simply appended the line:

`conda activate sdesign`

My environment name is `sdesign`. So it simply activates the environment every time I open a new terminal. Hope that helps.

Comment: Where to add line `conda activate sdesign` ?

Comment: I added the line in ".bashrc". So your terminal just runs that command every time you open a terminal. Make sure to replace 'sdesign' with the environment you want to be "default".

Comment: This is a question for Windows 10, and I suppose `.bashrc` is usually used in Linux or Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start `anaconda-navigator` with a particular environment [e.g `MyEnv` ] then For `Linux OS` I know a method. Maybe, it will be beneficial for someone. So, I'm sharing it.

1. First, completely close `anaconda-navigator` and the edit the file
2. Open `~/.anaconda/navigator/anaconda-navigator.ini`.

change

`default_env = '/home/user/anaconda3'`

to

`default_env = '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/MyEnv'`

> Note: Here `/home/{user will be different for everyone}/anaconda ...` like that.

You can also edit another options like

```
dataspell_path = 
pycharm_ce_path = 
pycharm_pro_path = 
vscode_path = /usr/share/code
```

and so on.

For windows there will be a file maybe in
`C:/User/AppData/local/anacond/anaconda-navigator.ini`  like that. Edit that like the solution. Surely that will also work.