# How to change the python environment in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I already have a python3.7 environment on my mac(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7),  I used that version for a long time until yesterday I installed anaconda3 accidentally, now the python kernel in my Jupiter notebook switched to python3.69 under anaconda, how can I change the default kernel of Jupiter notebook? I wanna use the python3.7 installed before. thx :)

Comment: So it means your jupyter notebook is using the python version inside anaconda3. Although it's not the answer to your question but you can do one thing.  Anaconda allows us to keep multiple version. So you can create a new environment of python3.7 and can access both version from jupyter notebook.  A nice explanation is given here : https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097

Comment: Also, have a look if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved it by uninstalling conda and reinstall jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

A Python bundled with Anaconda takes precedence over other Python's. All you need to do is to disable this behavior.

```sh
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Check [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974390/5101148) for more detail.