# Changing default conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I had been using Python2.7 for years under conda and ubuntu. Recently, for professional reasons, I had to switch to Python3, for which I created a new environment. However, as now I use exclusively Python3, I would like to make it the default environment (perhaps with an option of activating Python2, if I have to run some old code).

Is there a way to do this without reinstalling conda and keeping the installed packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default Anaconda python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment)

Comment: Indeed, it seems exaclty what I was looking for!