# In Anaconda/Python how to make my Virtual Environment as default environment when starting Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I have two Python environments in my Anaconda "base" and "image_analytics".
Every time I close and start Anaconda Prompt, I can see "base" environment activated by default. I have to write "conda activate image_analytics" every time. I want image_analytics environment to get activated every time by default I restart Anaconda Prompt. Any solution? I am a beginner. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi which os do you use?

Comment: @CanerBurcBASKAYA Windows 10 64-bit os

Comment: It might not be possible? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460907/11392177

Answer (score 5):

It actually quite simple, because the anaconda prompt is just a shortcut to `cmd` with an added call to activate the base env, which can be modified to start other envs

1. Locate the shortcut for anaconda prompt, either by going to `Start Menu->Right Clik Anaconda Prompt->Open File Location` or by navigating to the equivalent on your system of `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)`
2. Open the properties of the shortcut: `Right Click->Properties`
3. Modify the `Target` field. Original for me that activates the base env: `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\<Username>\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\<Username>\miniconda3`, which I can modify to e.g. start the `py37` env: `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\<Username>\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\<Username>\miniconda3\envs\py37`. Note that I simply modified the last path in that line to point to an environment instead of base.