# Fail to create virtual environment using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I use m1 Mac. I was trying to use Anaconda create a new virtual environment with python==3.6, currently having python==3.10. I have tried doing this both on DataSpell and terminal. But the error message kept pop up, "the package is not available from the current channels". I add conda-forge to the channel list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed your [Anaconda python environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436769/how-to-change-default-anaconda-python-environment) to be the virtualEnv's python?

If you don't there is no way for Anaconda to know which libraries you have installed.

You can also follow [this guide to Anaconda environments](https://whiteboxml.com/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-python-virtual-environments-with-conda) if you are lost.

Comment: I think my problem is mainly caused by failing to download python from anaconda channels, even though I have add multiple different channels.