# How to change default environment of jupyter notebook in windows?

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, jupyter

I want to change my default environment of jupyernote in conda. Right now I access that enironment using:
conda activate env_name
jupyter notebook
But this is not convinenet. What should I do to make env_name my default environment for jupyternotebook, That is when I open jupyter it opens in env_name.

I tried to change default environment using:
source activate env_name
But got an error
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It seems like your answer is in this thread already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28436769/9987623